# Unable to import 'flask_alchemy'

Tags: python, bash, terminal, flask-sqlalchemy

I created a virtual environment to work on my app, and install in the env folder pip, flask and flask_sqlalchemy, however when I try to import SQLAlchemy I got an error saying: Unable to import 'flask_sqlalchemy'.

I think my problem could be related with anaconda since when I run the terminal using bash this happens automatically:

```
cristovao@Pedro MINGW64 ~/Documents/MQS_Development
C:/Users/cristovao/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate

cristovao@Pedro MINGW64 ~/Documents/MQS_Development
$conda activate base
bash: conda: command not found

similar thing with cmd:

C:\Users\cristovao\Documents\MQS_Development
>C:/Users/cristovao/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate

(base) C:\Users\cristovao\Documents\MQS_Development
>conda activate base
```

Can anyone explain why my workspace terminal runs automatically the Anaconda scripts and how to avoid it?
And is it related with my import problem?

```
my workspace is organized this way:
|MQS_Development
  |flaskExperiments
    |env
    |app.py
    |models.py
```

Comment: Are you running your flask application within your environment, i.e did you activate your environment?

Comment: Yes I am @newbie99

Comment: Run `pip list` and let me see your modules.

Comment: (env) C:\Users\cristovao\Documents\MQS_Development\flaskExperiment>pip list

Package          Version

click            7.1.2
Flask            1.1.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.4.3
itsdangerous     1.1.0
Jinja2           2.11.2
MarkupSafe       1.1.1
pip              20.1.1
setuptools       39.0.1
SQLAlchemy       1.3.18
Werkzeug         1.0.1

Comment: In your post you said you have problems deactivating conda (base) env..and now you have an environment (env) with flask in it. Are u sure it doesn t work running `flask run` within the (env)?

Comment: this time I managed to open the terminal without conda

Comment: right now when I run python models.py it doesn't throw an error but it says that I have the same problem

Comment: Stacktrace with the new error, it might he sth else!

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand

Comment: it says pylint(importerror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my python interpreter I was using the Python 3.7.0 64-bit ('base': conda), so I changed it to Python 3.6.8 32-bit, problem solved.